How to prove that $A(f)(x) = \int_0^x e^t f(t) dt$ is bounded operator?
Let $A: C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$ be operator defined as
$$ A(f)(x) = \int_0^x e^t f(t) dt $$
for all $x \in [0,1]$ and $f \in C[0,1]$
How to prove that $A$ is bounded?
Also, similarly, how to prove that
$$ A_n (f)(x) = \int_0^x (\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{t^k}{k!}) f(t) dt $$
is also bounded?
My attempt:
$$ \lVert  Af \rVert = \left\| \int_0^x e^t f(t) dt \right\|= \sup_{x\in[0,1]} | \int_0^x e^t f(t) dt | \leq \sup_{x\in[0,1]} \int_0^x |e^t f(t)| dt $$
I am not very sure if it's okay to now say that the previous is less than $\int_0^1 |e^t f(t)| dt$, because the function under integral is positive. But from there, I am stuck.
About second part, is it direct corollary; $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{t^k}{k!} < e^t$ and integral is monotonous?

Hint: what can you say about the function $t \mapsto e^t$ on the compact set $[0,1]$? Also yes, you do have $\int_0^x g(t) \mathrm{d}t \leq \int_0^1 g(t) \mathrm{d}t$ for $x \in [0,1]$ and a positive function $g$ because you can use monotonicity of the integral (for example by using indicator functions to go back to integrals on the same starting set).

Assume the integrand takes on its largest absolute value on the whole interval and then integrate that value over the interval you necessarily get an integral larger than the original integral. If it's finite, the integral is bounded.

$$ \forall x\in[0,1],|A(f)(x)|\leqslant\int_0^x e^t|f(t)|dt\leqslant\|f\|_{\infty}\int_0^xe^tdt\leqslant (e-1)\|f\|_{\infty} $$
so $\|A(f)\|_{\infty}\leqslant (e-1)\|f\|_{\infty}$ and $A$ is a bounded operator.
